# Prevent max date to current date

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there anyway to prevent max selected date to current date in windows store Date Picker?
Only one solution i can think of on date changed event check selected date and reset it back to current.

Any better solution?

Comment: There is a MaxYear and MinYear properties you could use to limit the date a little

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker class (Win10) has a MinYear and MaxYear property. If you want to have it more fine-grained you need cope in the OnChanged.

Martin